# Sending ansi message to unicode window

Tags: c, winapi

If I register a window class with `RegisterClassExW` and I create a window of that class (let's call that window hwndA), If I send `SendMessageA(hwndA, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Hello")`, when hwndA receives WM_SETTEXT, will `lParam` always point to a unicode string even though I used `SendMessageA()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used `RegisterClassExW` to register the Window class, then yes.  Windows has special case logic for `SendMessage` and well known messages that use strings.  This includes `WM_SETTEXT`.

If the class of the Window was registered with the ANSI style function, `RegisterClassA` or `RegisterClassExA`, then all string parameters for subsequent window messages with strings will be ascii.  If the class of the Window was registered with the wide version (`RegisterClassW` or `RegisterClassExW`), then all subsequent window messages with strings will be unicode.

So in the general case, assuming your code is using Unicode APIs (the default these days), you always get a Unicode string in `WM_SETTEXT`.  Windows will convert the ansi string passed in through `SendMessageA` to a wide char string.

Here's what I did to confirm:

Take the following WndProc for example - modified from the default Visual Studio Win32 app template.

```
void LogPointer(const wchar_t* name, void* value, bool isUnicode)
{
    std::wostringstream ss;
    ss << L"Name=" << name << L"   value=" << std::hex << value << std::dec;
    if (isUnicode)
    {
        ss << L"    printed: " << (const wchar_t*)value;
    }
    else
    {
        ss << L"    printed: " << (const char*)value;
    }
    ss <<  L"\r\n";

    std::wstring str = ss.str();
    OutputDebugStringW(str.c_str());
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char* psz = "Hello world";
    wchar_t* wpsz = L"Bye Bye";

    switch (message)
    {

        case WM_SETTEXT:
        {
            LogPointer(L"psz", psz, false);
            LogPointer(L"wpsz", wpsz, true);
            LogPointer(L"lParam", (void*)lParam, true);


            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
                case IDM_ABOUT:
                {
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"Invoking SendMessageA with ansi string\r\n");
                    SendMessageA(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)psz);

                    OutputDebugStringW(L"\r\nInvoking SendMessageW with wide string\r\n");
                    SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)wpsz);
                    break;
                }
```

The output is as follows:

```
Invoking SendMessageA with ansi string
Name=psz   value=0096338C    printed: Hello world
Name=wpsz   value=0096339C    printed: Bye Bye
Name=lParam   value=005ADE78    printed: Hello world

Invoking SendMessageW with wide string
Name=psz   value=0096338C    printed: Hello world
Name=wpsz   value=0096339C    printed: Bye Bye
Name=lParam   value=0096339C    printed: Bye Bye
```

Now observe the value of `lParam` in the two sets of output log lines.

In the case of `SendMessageA`, the pointer value of `lParam` matches neither that of `psz` nor `wpsz`.  Windows, underneath the hood recognizes that it needs to convert the ansi string to a wide char.  So it does the conversion for you and actually sends a different allocated string that it manages.

In the case of SendMessageW, `lParam==wpsz`.  No conversion was done.  Windows just passed the `lParam` value straight to the `WndProc` call.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Hello");
```

or

```
SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"Hello");
```

in both case `lParam` (in windowproc) always point to a unicode string. in first case `SendMessageA` - system allocate memory from heap or stack, and convert ansi `"Hello"` to unicode and you got pointer to this memory.
in second case `SendMessageW` - you got direct pointer to `L"Hello"` in window proc

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use SetWindowLongPtrA, the callback function lParam (WM_SETTEXT) will point to an ANSI string, so if you need wchar_t in the callback function, use SetWindowLongPtrW beforehand

Answer (score -3):

CreateWindow A or W make changes not regstyle.W window may interpret it as wide chars.

Comment: It is the call to [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx) that determines whether a window is a Unicode or ANSI window. Both `CreateWindowA` and `CreateWindowW` can be used with any window class, but neither changes the character set of the registered window class.

Comment: @IInspectable so you have Curaçao class and wanna use it in CreateWindowA.This is kinda garbage dude.

Comment: Are you preparing your next month in the penalty box? Anyway, the character `ç` is available in several ANSI codepages, so yes, `CreateWindowA` can create a window of class `Curaçao`. It's not recommended, but possible. At any rate, it would greatly help if you stopped commenting on stuff you haven't got the slightest clue. Your answer is wrong. My comment is right. There's nothing for you to add. Seriously.

Comment: `CreateWindowA can create a window of class L"Curaçao".` thats clue i'd write about early in this article

Comment: `CreateWindowA` doesn't take a wide character string literal. But there is nothing wrong with passing `"Curaçao"`, if the current ANSI code page can represent all symbols. At any rate, the point I'm trying to make is simple: Your proposed answer is wrong. See [IsWindowUnicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529.aspx) for example: *"The character set of a window is determined by the use of the RegisterClass function."*